# Error while using the plot function of the package moveHMM in R

Tags: r, plot, hidden-markov-models

I have fitted a Hidden Markov Model using the `moveHMM` library in R.

```
hmm_model <- fitHMM(data = move_data, nbStates = 3, stepPar0 = stepPar0, anglePar0 = anglePar0, formula = ~1)
```

The result makes sense biologically speaking and I do not have any warning issued.

As indicated in the package documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/moveHMM/vignettes/moveHMM-guide.pdf) I tried to plot the object.

I tried the following commands:

```
plot(hmm_model, type = "states")
plot(hmm_model)
```

but I always get the same error message:

```
> plot(hmm_model, type = "states")
Decoding states sequence... DONE
Error in if (maxdens > ymax & maxdens < 1.5 * ymax) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Has anyone ever encountered this issue and would have any recommendations on how to solve it?

Here is the structure of the object that should be plotted:

```
> str(hmm_model)
List of 7
 $ data       :'data.frame':    16515 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ ID         : chr [1:16515] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
  ..$ step       : num [1:16515] 0.327 0.346 0.346 0.346 0.346 ...
  ..$ angle      : num [1:16515] NA -0.156381 -0.004527 -0.001887 -0.000926 ...
  ..$ x          : num [1:16515] 582629 582629 582628 582628 582628 ...
  ..$ y          : num [1:16515] -2195359 -2195359 -2195358 -2195358 -2195358 ...
  ..$ (Intercept): num [1:16515] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mle        :List of 5
  ..$ stepPar : num [1:3, 1:3] 3.43e-15 8.36e+09 1.00 8.31e-02 1.13e-01 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "mean" "sd" "zero-mass"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "state 1" "state 2" "state 3"
  ..$ anglePar: num [1:2, 1:3] 1.31e-03 2.83 1.32e-03 2.23e+01 -3.31e-10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "mean" "concentration"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "state 1" "state 2" "state 3"
  ..$ beta    : num [1, 1:6] -6.91 -37.97 -9.65 -25.74 -0.43 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "intercept"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "1 -> 2" "1 -> 3" "2 -> 1" "2 -> 3" ...
  ..$ delta   : num [1:3] 2.67e-10 1.00 1.32e-14
  ..$ gamma   : num [1:3, 1:3] 9.99e-01 6.44e-05 3.38e-01 9.93e-04 1.00 ...
 $ mod        :List of 6
  ..$ minimum   : num -27526
  ..$ estimate  : num [1:23] -33.31 -2.49 1.61 22.85 -2.18 ...
  ..$ gradient  : num [1:23] 0 -0.00268 0 0 0.00216 ...
  ..$ hessian   : num [1:23, 1:23] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ code      : int 1
  ..$ iterations: int 73
 $ conditions :List of 6
  ..$ stepDist     : chr "gamma"
  ..$ angleDist    : chr "vm"
  ..$ zeroInflation: logi TRUE
  ..$ estAngleMean : logi TRUE
  ..$ stationary   : logi FALSE
  ..$ formula      :Class 'formula'  language ~1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 $ rawCovs    :'data.frame':    16515 obs. of  0 variables
 $ knownStates: NULL
 $ nlmTime    : 'proc_time' Named num [1:5] 66.16 0.72 66.88 NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "user.self" "sys.self" "elapsed" "user.child" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "moveHMM" "list"
```

Many thanks (I do not really know how to make this issue reproducible, so I am asking about the error message to get a first idea).

Comment: Please provide your data with `dput(hmm_model)`. `if()` looks for `TRUE`/`FALSE`. If the `condition` inside `if()`  evaluates to `NA` one gets `Error in if (something) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Therefore, we have to check `maxdens` and `ymax` I suspect.

Comment: You can check manually step-by-step. Look at the relevant lines `plot_moveHMM` (lines 68, 77-82): https://github.com/TheoMichelot/moveHMM/blob/c36d50b2fd1ec8c19c7fcf27f1d691bc5811bc75/R/plot_moveHMM.R#L77

Comment: Thank you v much for your comment, it has been really helpful. It appears that the `prepData` function does not handle well my stationary points (if the animal has not moved between two consecutive time points (i.e., the coordinates are the same)) and this leads to NAs since the step length is zero and the turning angle is undefined. I still don't know how to solve this but at least I know now where it comes from.

Comment: Nice to hear from you! That is a good step forward I think. A simple trick, which could be quite inaccurate in your situation, is to replace `0` with another value, e.g. `.001`.

Comment: Yes but the 0s are introduced by the `prepData` function. My dataframe contains 3 columns, ID, x, y (coordinates in UTM format). When multiple rows have the exact same x and y values (no movement), the prepData function seems to introduce a 0 for step and NA for angle.

Comment: As mentioned in my an above comment, it is really difficult to help without having the data.

Comment: I am sorry I do not manage with the `dput` because the result is really huge and I cannot copy/paste :'(  meanwhile I have kept working on your idea to check manually step-by-step in the relevant lines: so far, I have isolated the fact that `> max(distData$step$total)
[1] NaN` and the first lines of the `getPlotData` function gives this: `> getPlotData(m = hmm_model, type = "dist")
$step
            step state1    state2 state3     total
1   0.0000000000    NaN       Inf      0       NaN`  ; all the other lines seem correct.

Comment: I will also add this in case it helps: `> summary(hmm_model$data$step)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
0.000000 0.009861 0.019897 0.077998 0.055688 0.842043        1 
> summary(hmm_model$data$angle)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
-3.1263 -0.0055  0.0001  0.0012  0.0060  3.1298    1010`

Comment: @Friede now that I have made some progress, I have opened a more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77795698/package-issue-trying-to-plot-a-hidden-markov-model. Hope this helps and thanks again for your comments.